# Проблема при вызове класса JFileChooser через другого класса

Tags: java

Всем привет. Разрабатываю проект в Eclipse на языке программирование Java. Проблема заключается в следующим: Создал класс `FileChooser.java` и основной класс `Main.java`. Написал код для `FileChooser.java` вот так:

```
public class FileChooser extends JPanel{

    private FileChooser(){
        final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        final JButton open = new JButton("Open");

        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:/Users/Elmar/Desktop"));
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose Your Project");
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

        if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(open) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    }
}
```

При всем этом я вызываю метод `main` в классе `Main.java` таким образом

```
openProject.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        FileChooser.main(args);
    }
});`
```

И когда все готово я запускаю программу и при нажатие на кнопку Open программа зависает и перестает работать. Мне `JFileChooser` нужен в отдельном классе из-за этого я так написал код. Буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Метод public static void main(String[] args){} - не совсем обычный метод. это, если можно так выразиться, точка входа в приложение, поэтому, пока не придет понимание происходящего, для простоты действуйте по правилу: "одно приложение один метод main". 
Посему попробуйте написать класс FileChooser без него:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class FileChooser extends JFileChooser{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2339847367533082834L;
    private final JButton openButton;

    public FileChooser(){
        openButton = new JButton("Open");
    }

    public void startFileChooser(){
        setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:/Users/Elmar/Desktop"));
        setDialogTitle("Choose Your Project");
        setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        if(showOpenDialog(openButton) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            //после нажатия на кнопку выводит путь к выбранной директории
            System.out.println(getSelectedFile());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.startFileChooser();
    }

}
```

Разумеется, вместо FileChooser.main(args) следует сделать так: 
new FileChooser().startFileChooser().

Обратите также внимание на использование конструктора.
Вы его используете, чтобы запустить логику. Так делать не стоит по многим причинам. Для этого существуют обычные методы. А конструктор по сути своей призван делать две вещи: создавать экземпляр класса и инициализировать поля.

Comment: Сделал как вы написали, но скажу то что не работает данный метод. Прописывал как только мог. И сам как знаю и как вы написали. Но все без результатов. В основном класса прописал `new FileChooser().startFileChooser();` но тоже без результатов.

Comment: Что значит не работает? Какой результат выполнения и что именно вы делаете?

Comment: Добавил в код ответа касс мейн. Пробуйте запустить через этот метод, должен запуститься FileChooser, если запуститься, то стало быть вы что-то не так запускали

Comment: Значит я проверил приложение через диспетчер задач и узнал что класс FileChooser.java запускается. Но он не открывается поверх основного класса(Main.java). Как можно исправить данный проблему ?

Comment: класс мейн давайте, из которого вызов осуществляется, будем исправлять... вы выложили класс, написали, что в нем проблема. в ответе я переписал класс таким образом, чтобы он отрабатывал корректно. проблемы, порождаемые другим классом, разумеется, остались за пределами ответа по той простой причине, что вы их сами оставили за пределами своего вопроса.

Comment: Нашел решение. Вы правы. У меня в Main,java было одно такая функция `setAlwaysOnTop()` и на нем было true типа bool, Я его убрал и теперь началось показыватся FileChooser. Хочу сказать вам спасибо за помощь. Очень вам признателен за помощь

Comment: Не за что. пользуйтесь и радуйтесь, изучайте java

Answer (score 0):

Переименуй main во что то другое
А ещё `

```
if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(open) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

        }
```

ничего не делает.

Comment: Хорошо бы дать пояснение.